how to Access Internet of RDP
I bought an RDP with Windows 10 that has a very fast internet speed. Can I use this internet on my local PC so that my local PC's internet speed becomes faster as well?

No, your internet will only be as fast as the connection from your router to your ISP. You can't remote into another box on the internet that has faster internet, and download files to your computer at a faster rate.
